# php fetch_assoc only shows one row for multiple same rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

I expect that query result for the following code contains two rows with exact same value, but it only shows one for these two rows, other rows show correctly, the query works correctly when I run it in the db. The solution I find is adding unique id in select query but I want to know why php skip one row.

```
 $queryitem=$newconn->query("select productname, qty from table where condition");
 $result=array();
 $count=0;
 while ($item=$queryitem->fetch_assoc()){
    $result[$count]=$item;
    $count+=1;
 }
```

Expect result(query result shows in db):

```
      productname    qty
      aaa             10
      aaa             10
      bbb              5
```

Fecth result:

```
          productname    qty
          aaa             10
          bbb              5
```

Comment: `$count` is not needed, `$result[]=$item;`

Comment: please do a `print_r($result)`. also, are you, by any chance using `for($i=1;...)`?

Comment: I did print_r($result) before and it shows that fetch skipped second aaa record, for loop is not good for my situation, by the way my current solution is including id in the select query so records became different, but I want to know the reason and whether there is alternative way